# Get snapshot ID from snapshot creation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am working on a script to create a snapshot, then create a volume from the snapshot just made. My intention is to take an existing volume that is unencrypted, snapshot it, create a new volume that is encrypted; detach the old volume and attach the new volume.

This a section of code where I am stopping the instance to do a 'cold' snapshot. I need to make sure I am getting the Id of the snapshot I just created.

```
                ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=[i.id]).stop()
                response = ec2.create_snapshot(
                    VolumeId = g,
                    TagSpecifications=[
                        {
                            'ResourceType': 'snapshot',
                            'Tags' : [
                                {
                                    'Key': 'Name',
                                    'Value': snap_name
                                },
                                {
                                    'Key': 'Backup',
                                    'Value': 'Daily'
                                },
                                {
                                    'Key': 'Costcenter',
                                    'Value': i_div
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    ],
                Description = 'Snapshot of volume ({})'.format(v.id)
                )
                print(response)
```

This is what I get when I print the response:

```
ec2.Snapshot(id='snap-0ca01c231e5db53d8')
```

I am having a difficult time splitting the response or figuring out how to get the snapshot Id out of the response. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: JellyCSC,
Thank you for quick and accurate response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a `response.id`. Reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Snapshot.id